# Partial match using If condition in macro vba

Tags: excel, vba

Currently working on a project where I need to find if a file is selected is correct or not. So I'm using a partial match using if condition. Below is the code for refernece. The code gives out Runtime error '424' Object Required.

```
     `
    Sub Fetch_Files()

        Dim OB1 As Workbook, FTO As Variant,strSheetName as string

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        FTO= Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse For your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx*),*xlsx*")

            If FTO <> False then

              Set OB1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(FTO)
              OB1.Worksheets(1).Activate
              strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

                        If strSheetName.value = "*abc*" Then
                          'Call abc
                        else
                           MsgBox ("Please abc file")
                        End If

            Else

                MsgBox ("Please Select Files")
                Exit Sub

            End If


        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        End Sub
    `
```

Comment: Your `FTO` variable is of type `Variant`, which doesn't have `FullName` property.

Comment: @JohnyL: even if I used FTO, then it will bypass & move to else condition. Any suggestion would be greatful.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename), `GetOpenFilename` returns string or Boolean. These types don't have `FullName` property.

Comment: @JohnyL I've added more code. This time I've  open workbook & have taken sheetname store in a variable & finding out partial match with variable, but still give same error.

Comment: `strSheetName` variable is of type `String` - it doesn't have `Name` property

Comment: @JohnyL Thanks for your help. I've founded out solutions & posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution has been found.
I've used OB1.Worksheet(1).Name using **like** keyword.

```
If FTO <> False then

              Set OB1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(FTO)

                        If  OB1.Worksheets(1).Name like "*abc*" Then ' improve code
                          'Call abc
                        else
                           MsgBox ("Please abc file")
                        End If

            Else

                MsgBox ("Please Select Files")
                Exit Sub

            End If
```